# optional arguments and default value

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript does the following 2 functions does the same thing and would you pick one over another?

```
var multiply = function(arg1, arg2) {
             arg1 && (arg1 = 0);
             arg2 && (arg2 = 0);
             return arg1*arg2;
          }


var multiply = function(arg1, arg2) {
             arg1 = arg1 || 0;
             arg2 = arg2 || 0;
             return arg1*arg2;
          }
```

the reason i am asking is i saw something like this for the first time

```
  function(path, limit) {
     var ref = firebaseRef(path);
     limit && (ref = ref.limit(limit)); //if i understood correctly this line does an assignment based on condition without an if statement
     return $firebase(ref);
  }
```

Comment: Yes, you have the first function backwards. It actually sets `arg1` to `0` everytime `arg1` is actually truthy: http://jsfiddle.net/t5knF/ It should be `arg1 || (arg1 = 0)` and that's then pretty much the same the second one.

Comment: i dont know why i thought it would work as in the last function

Comment: @basilikum and others correctly pointed out that the first function is wrong. However if the first and second functions are meant to show the difference between `&&` and `||`, then the first one would actually be `!arg1 && (arg1 = 0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function(path, limit) {
    var ref = firebaseRef(path);
    limit && (ref = ref.limit(limit));   // Important
    return $firebase(ref);
}
```

The Important line, can be written like this

```
if (limit) {
    ref = ref.limit(limit);
}
```

But if you wanted to write it like the first way, you would have done,

```
ref = limit && ref.limit(limit)
```

This has one problem, when `limit` is Falsy `&&` immediately returns the evaluated Falsy value of `limit`, so `ref` is Falsy now. You wouldn't have wanted this, I believe.

At the end of the day, as a programmer, readability and maintainability of the code of the code what we write matters. So, I would recommend using an explicit `if` check, which I mentioned at the beginning of the answer.

**Note:** Also, as noted by others, the first `multiply` should have been like this

```
var multiply = function(arg1, arg2) {
    arg1 || (arg1 = 0);
    arg2 || (arg2 = 0);
    return arg1 * arg2;
}
```

Even better, I would have written it like this

```
var multiply = function(arg1, arg2) {
    return (arg1 || 0) * (arg2 || 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are variable assignments which evaluate differently on the logical operation.

For example **expr1 && expr2** will return `expr1` if `expr1` returns `false` otherwise the variable assignment will evaluate to the second expression (i.e. `expr2`).

Using the logical-or operation will return `expr1` if it evaluates to `true`, otherwise it will return `expr2`.

Consider the following:

```
// Logical AND
var a1 =  true && true;     // t && t returns true
var a2 =  true && false;    // t && f returns false
var a3 = false && true;     // f && t returns false
var a4 = false && (3 == 4); // f && f returns false
var a5 = "Cat" && "Dog";    // t && t returns Dog
var a6 = false && "Cat";    // f && t returns false
var a7 = "Cat" && false;    // t && f returns false

// Logical OR
var o1 =  true || true;     // t || t returns true
var o2 = false || true;     // f || t returns true
var o3 =  true || false;    // t || f returns true
var o4 = false || (3 == 4); // f || f returns false
var o5 = "Cat" || "Dog";    // t || t returns Cat
var o6 = false || "Cat";    // f || t returns Cat
var o7 = "Cat" || false;    // t || f returns Cat
```

For more information, see: [Mozilla Developer Network on Logical Operator Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FExpressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators)

Answer (score 1):

I think the first one will actually do the opposite of what you want. Let's test this with a few cases:

```
arg1 && (arg1 = 0);
```

If `arg1` is 0, or any other falsy value, so the execution goes as follows:
0 (meaning false) AND an assignment. The expression will immediately return false without executing the `arg1 = 0` statement, because `false || (t/f)` always returns false.

If `arg1` is 1, or any other truthy value, so we have:

1 (meaning true) AND an assignment. The assignment *will* run this time, because it has to see what the second condition returns. Therefore, `arg1` will be set to 0.

The correct snippet is the second.